# What is the theory basis for "Centering improves the numerical properties of both the polynomial and the fitting algorithm."?

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, rounding-error

I have a set of $N$ data, $(x_i,y_i)$,which comes from sampling on $sin$ function. Assuming the sampling period is $T$, then $x_i = iT$. If  interpolating them without centering, namely $x_i = T, 2T, 3T .... nT$, the resulting polynimial is easy to diverge when $n$ increases. However, if centering $x_i$, namely replace $x_i$ with $\hat{x_i} = iT-NT/2$, the result is much better.
It seems this kind of centering is good for having a stable interpolating algorithm. What's the theory behind this phenomenon? Many thanks :)

For a better understanding of this question, let's take an example. Assuming $n=3$. and the polynomial to be determined has the form

$ f(t) = a +bx + cx^2$.

A sequence of three samples from the sin function is :

$ (T,sin(T))$  $\:-$   $(2T, sin(2T))$ $(3T, sin(3T))$

We can use this sequence of data to solve the above polynomial. However,
if we centering the sequence of data to

$ (-T,sin(T))$  $(0, sin(2T))$ $(T, sin(3T))$

the resultant interpolated polynomial would be more stable then the previous one.

A few more words: the above example is just an simplified example. The phenomenon is only obvious when N is large.

Comment: It would be a very good idea to edit your question to include a specific examples which illustrates the effect that you have seen. You should also state how you are measuring the quality of your approximations. Which norm are you using? I believe these changes will increase your chance of getting a good answer.

Comment: @CarlChristian Thanks for suggestions and a simple example is added to the question. I thinks the reason is about "condition number". Centering the sequence of data will lead to a smaller condition number of the coefficient matrix of the linear equations to be solved.